# Filter a data frame containing NaN values, results in empty data frame as result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frames

> Dataframe:
>
> A   B       C         D        E
>
> 0   X   NaN  Y        NaN     Z
>
> 1   X   X       X        Y         R
>
> 2   S   H       NaN   NaN    T

I want to filter the rows in the dataframe 1 with the columns A,B,C,D values.

I wrote my code to filter it using df.loc

```
filtered_df = df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'X') & (df1['B'] == 'X') & (df1['C'] == 'X') & (df1['D'] == 'Y')]
```

I get the result correctly.

but when I run the same code for a value containing NaN in its columns, say

```
filtered_df = df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'X') & (df1['B'] == np.nan) & (df1['C'] == 'Y') & (df1['D'] == np.nan)]
```

then it is returning a empty dataframe.

filtering fails.

I tried the same comparison with None, isnull(), == ''.

Also tried using `df.fillna('')` and then comparing with == ''.

but everything returns empty dataframe.

Kindly help out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because `np.nan != np.nan`, actually. This is required in the IEEE spec if I recall correctly. You can't check if a value is nan by comparing equality. (Because "not a number" isn't "equal" to something else that is also "not a number"). Just use `isna()` on the column, e.g. `df['B'].isna()`.

Comment: `df1.loc[(df1['A'] == 'X') & (df1['B'].isnull()) & (df1['C'] == 'Y') & (df1['D'].isnull())]`

Comment: Note that `isnull()` as above is simply an alias for `isna()`, so they're completely equivalent---use whichever you prefer.

Comment: But as mentioned in my query, isnull() is also not working and is being responded with a empty dataframe